# How can I call a csharp variable in .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

In code behind page I create a variable like this (it belongs to one of the class)

```
string login_status = "you are not logged in";
```

I want to show this variable value in my Default.aspx page. What do I do?

Comment: It depends on which class and where it is defined and instantiated.

Comment: Jon's comment is true, but if the control is on the Default.aspx page and your code is on the Default.aspx.cs, the code in markpsmith's answer is the most basic way of having it displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a variable of type string with protected access modifier and call it on your web page using:

```
<%= login_status %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Drop a label onto your aspx page:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

then in the codebehind, say:

```
Label1.Text = login_status;
```

Comment: It did not work, do I need to access labe1 from .aspx page in special way or just the code above should work?

Comment: what I was really hoping is the asp page loads the value from codebehind page (in this casse variable). The c# page should only set the value of the variable. I need some conditions what value I want to display and majority of the code is in .aspx page.

Comment: Yes, that is how it would work. If you add the control Label1 to the aspx page, the codebehind page will know what Label1 is, and will set its Text using the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Add a label control onto the default.aspx page.  It will automatically be named Label1.

From your code behind you can place your string into the label.

```
Label1.Text = login_status
```

Comment: Check out .... [link]http://v4.programminghelp.com/asp-net/working-with-the-label-control-in-asp-net-4-0-using-c/

Answer (score 1):

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/02/15/asp.net_tip_-_use_the_label_control_correctly.aspx

you can use asp.Literal control instead of Label.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a control to the page (label, literal) that will display this nicely and set it's value in the code behind.

You can also user runat="server" on any html tag to set it's inner html (etc) in the code behind.

Finally if you want to do it the 'quick' way you can put <%=login_status%> in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do

First Variables you trying to access should be **protected** or **public**

Then you can access these variables like

**`<% Response.Write(login_status); %>`**

or 
 **`<%= login_status%>`**

or you can use control like asp control like labels and change its Text property on code behind